# Rxjs forkJoin not executing in Angular Route Guard

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have built a user permission service that fetches permissions from the server for a given user. I further build a route guard that leverages this service to determine if the user has all of the permissions listed in the route. To accomplish this, I iterate over the permissions listed on the route and create an observable for each as the user permission service is queried. Once all the observables are created, I `forkJoin` over them to ensure that they are all true.

In my general testing of the permission service, I'm able to reliably get a result back every time. And if I manually iterate over the returned array and subscribe to each observable manually, it works as desired. However, no matter what I do, the `forkJoin` never appears to execute. If I replace my generated observables with an array of `[of(true),of(true)]`, it behaves as expected. I'm not quite sure what's going on.

User Service:

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserPermissionsService {
  private _permissions = new BehaviorSubject<AppliedPermissions>(null);
  public permissionSnapshot: AppliedPermissions;
  public permissions: Observable<AppliedPermissions> = this._permissions.asObservable();

  constructor(private _userService: UserService) {
  }

  init(): Observable<AppliedPermissions> {
    return this._userService.getPermissions()
      .pipe(tap(p => {
        this._permissions.next(p)
        this.permissionSnapshot = p;
      }));
  }

  destroy(): void {
    this._permissions?.complete();
  }

  hasPermission(permission: string): Observable<boolean> {
    return this._permissions.pipe(
      switchMap(value => value ? of(value) : this.init()),
      map(response => {
        const perm = response.permissions
          .find(el => el.permissionName === permission);

        if (!perm)
          return false;

        return perm.allow;
      }),
      catchError(_ => of(false))
    );
  }

  inRole(role: string): Observable<boolean> {
    return this._permissions.pipe(
      switchMap(value => value ? of(value) : this.init()),
      map(response => {
        return !!response.roles.find(el => el === role);
      }),
      catchError(_ => of(false))
    );
  }
}
```

Route Guard

```js
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class PermissionGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private _userPermissionsService: UserPermissionsService) {
  }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    const permissions = route.data.permissions as Array<string>;
    const observables = permissions.map(p => this._userPermissionsService.hasPermission(p));

    return forkJoin(observables)
      .pipe(
        tap(e => {
          console.log(e)
        }),
        map(e => e.every(v => v)),
        catchError(_ => of(false))
      );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`forkJoin` only emits when all of the observable have completed. Since `hasPermission` depends on BehaviorSubject which does not complete, then the `forkJoin` never emits.

You can use `zip` combined with `take(1)` to do what you want.

```
return zip(...observables)
  .pipe(
    take(1),
    tap(e => {
      console.log(e)
    }),
    map(e => e.every(v => v)),
    catchError(_ => of(false))
  );
```

Comment: Oddly enough, `zip` is exhibiting the exact same behavior as `forkJoin` was. Tossing a breakpoint on the `tap`, it appears it never executes.

Comment: However, it looks like `combineLatest` may actually give me what I'm after. But I'm not sure if that could cause issues if there's potentially a race condition.

Comment: There isn't any theoretical reason (I can think of) why combineLatest would work over zip since both wait until all observables have emitted a value. Are you getting any hits in the catchError callback?

Comment: Nope, no errors at all. The tap method never gets called. None of the observables in the chain do.

Comment: I did a beginner mistake. You need to spread the `zip(...observables)`. Sorry for that. That's the reason combineLatest works. It has a different signature.